# Degrees of Freedom of Counting Experiment

Tags: statistics

Lets say every hour I count the number of birds outside my window. I do this for 20 hours a day and record my data so each day is a row, and the first column is the number of intervals I counted zero birds, and the next column is for 1 and then 2 and so on. So its essentially in a histogram form, and I have data for 100 days.

I add up the data in groups of 5 days and compare the distribution with a gaussian and obtain chi squared values. I now have 20 chi squared values and want to see how well they fit an expected chi squared distribution, but I need the degrees of freedom. I am fairly new to statistical analysis, but would the degrees of freedom just be 1 since I am only counting 1 thing? or how is it determined?

edit: I know Poisson would make more sense. This question is mainly about degrees of freedom

Answer (score 0):

The counting process you are describing is probably better modeled as a Poisson random variable rather than a $\chi^2$ variable.  The histogram you created of how many times you observed $N = k$ birds per hour increment for $k = 0, 1, \ldots$ should follow a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$:  $$\Pr[N = k] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I should've mentioned that. It was just an example I came up with. I'm more concerned with the degrees of freedom

Comment: The $\chi^2$ degrees of freedom $\nu$ is modeled by the number of standard normal variates; i.e., if $Y = Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + \cdots + Z_\nu^2$ where $Z_i \sim {\rm Normal}(0,1)$, then $Y \sim \chi^2(\nu)$.  Unless you can provide some rationalization for using this model, choosing an appropriate $\nu$ is not meaningful.